# how do I point to the document from which I want to import (using importNode())?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function in an html document, that should bring a node from another html document.

I read about `importNode()`, but I do not understand how should I point to the document from which I want to import. I don't find any url anywhere.
MDN shows:

```
var node = document.importNode(externalNode, deep);
```

Is `externalNode` a url? Any clarification greatly appreciated! (I'm new to this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to the other html document can come from an iframe, which will have the url set to the src.

HTML

```
<iframe src="/my-other-url.html"></iframe>
```

Javascript (Taken from Mozilla docs)

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
var oldNode = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("myNode");
var newNode = document.importNode(oldNode, true);
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newNode);
```

Refer to this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode) from Mozilla.

Comment: the <iframe src="/my-other-url.html"></iframe> I was missing! hahah I had seen the javascript. As I said, new!! Thank you so much! :)